# Is a smart query service for stackexchange sites welcome here?

Tags: discussion, search, stack-exchange, data-explorer, data-dump

StackExchange sites has been a great source for me to find answers to many technical questions, but sometimes I needs a little more than what a generic search engine can provided.

Having the technology, we built a data service for stackexchange.com sites according to the data schema published. The semi-auto generated data service includes comprehensive information about the data source. It is able to guide a user to perform structured query against any of the data sets (tables) publically available. The queries can be of any complexity, including performing composite querys that combined keyword searches (using Lucene.Net) and traditional SQL query in an arbitrary expression. (see, e.g the Posts table query interface [see here](http://stackex-server.archymeta.com:8081/Post/MainView), it is backed by a virtual Windows server and a PostgreSQL database engine).

An initial article was published on the codeproject that introduced the service, [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675345/Service-for-StackExchange-Implementing-a-Data-Prov) (ignore the download count there, some unknown search bot might be at work).

The question is: is such kind of data service welcome by the users here? If so, does any one has interests and resources to host it on the web?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, as I wasn't using it, but how would it be better than http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new ?

Comment: It has something like intelli-sense to help a user to compose query and it is a data service that can be called against by software [see is a portal that uses it's API](http://query.demo.archymeta.com:8081/). Further, it does not depend on specific database engine.

Comment: FYI: *The server at query.demo.archymeta.com is taking too long to respond.*

Comment: There's already an API available ([docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)), if you want to contribute you can do so on [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)

Comment: It may be because you are in Europe and the server is in China. That is why I am asking for interested parties to host it elsewhere:-)

Comment: @Stijn(2), yes I know. But it is a little limited for me. The data service here can be used to do full relational data entity graph manipulation and query.

Comment: @SFD-jinan That could be it yeah. And for the record, I'm not trying to be negative about your idea, just pointing out some info in case you didn't know them yet :)